# Getting private key from ECC certificate

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography, certificate, x509certificate

How can I get the private key from a certificate I imported with a .p12 file (contains private key too)? I am using .net

I have tried loading the certificate from the store and use .PrivateKey that is only for RSA and DSA because I get an error.

My certificate is ECC which I cannot find much information about. I tried using

```
certificate.GetECDsaPrivateKey()
```

but it returns null? What can I do to get the private key from the cert store? I need this private key to form a shared secret with a public key I have. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

edit: i converted the p12 into a .pem and can see that there is a private key in there

Comment: Are you sure that your certificate uses ECC key? What key parameters are in use?

Comment: I am almost positive, in windows MMC, I go to the certificate and under in the public key field it says ECC, I would imagine the private key is aswell. The public key parameter is ECDH_P256

Comment: Does MMC show key icon with a text "You have a private key that corresponds to this certificate"?

Comment: Yes it has that also, I want to mention how I got the certificate was through my macOS on virtualbox, generated the certificates in keychain and exported the certificate with it's key as a .p12 file and imported that onto my windows machine.

Comment: Does the certificate have a Key Usage Extension? If so, does it have any of DigitalSignature, NonRepudiation, KeyCertSign, or CrlSign set?  Is the public key algorithm id-ecPublicKey (1.2.840.10045.2.1), or is it possibly id-ecDH (1.3.132.1.12)?  Does does GetECDsaPublicKey() work, or also return null?

Comment: Under key usage it says: Key Encipherment, Key Agreement (28). I cant find any digitalsignature, nonrepudiation, keycertsign, or crlsign. I believe that it is edch because that is the algorithm used to get the symmetric key and GetECDsaPublicKey() returns null

Comment: Looks you would need a `ECDhCertificateExtensions` object rather than an `ECDsaCertificateExtensions` object; however that class does not exist.